# Rigging Problem

Tags: rigging

I am a newbie to the Blender.
I always have some confusion about the rigging.
Hoping you can provide some insight into a bit of confusion i have.
If you are Maya user before, u might know there are three different way to let
 a Joint follow another one.
1, you can parent them.
2,you can constrain them.
3, you can use the relationship Editor to connect their parameters.
The reason you use three different way to constrain the two joints is that have a clear outline and let the main control curve can scale the Object.

So, I want know is there any similar way to control joints?
Take the project as example.
[image]
If I want the L_Arm IK01 follow the Spine02 and I do not want parent them, is there any other way to achieve it?

Could you give me some advises about the blender rigging?

Comment: your question is too broad, you should ask questions one by one. About your precise question: you want L_Arm IK01 to follow Spine02 but you don't want to parent them, but why don't you want to parent them, as it would allow you to make arm follow spine? You could give the arm a child constraint but I'm not sure it's the solution. If you want your arm to be independent, IK is precisely here for this purpose, so maybe give a bit more details...

Comment: In general, in blender you can use parenting, constraints or drivers to copy some or all of one object's transformations to another.